# Iphone device height relative to earth or previous position

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to identify that the device has moved up or down relative to earth or from its previous position.

I just want to check if user has moved the device up or down

Comment: UIAccelerometer Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html

Answer (score 0):

Other than the accelerometer, I can't think of any way to do that... If you're trying to find relative elevation I think you're out of luck, but the accelerometer will track a vertical phone movement.